# jQuery show/hide table rows based on clicked buttons

Tags: jquery, sorting, filter, html-table

I have a table that has multiple rows which again has multiple cell.
Above my table I have buttons based on the data in the table, there are 2 rows with each an amount of buttons, 1 is "type" the other 1 is "weight" so it may look something like this:

- 2500
- 2300
- 2400
- 1
- 2
- 3

So there is 6 buttons 3 are representing weight. The other 3 are the type of cars. So when I press the button "2500" 3 rows will show and the others will hide. But then I want to show all the cars that weigh "2500" and are of type "1", So I click the button. But when i click "1" it will show all the rows which have type "1" so it totally ignores the 2500. 
So how do i fix this?

This is the jQuery im currently using.

```
var criteria_type;
var criteria_gewicht;

$(".button_option").click(function() {

    if ($(this).hasClass("active_option")) {
        $(this).removeClass("active_option");
        if($(this).hasClass("filter_button_gewicht")){
            criteria_gewicht = "";
        }
        if($(this).hasClass("filter_button_type")){
            criteria_type = "";
        }
    }
    else{
        $(this).parent().find(".active_option").removeClass("active_option");
        $(this).addClass("active_option");
        if($(this).hasClass("filter_button_gewicht")){
            criteria_gewicht = $(this).val();
        }
        if($(this).hasClass("filter_button_type")){
            criteria_type = $(this).val();
        }
    }
    datadinges();

});


function datadinges(){

    if (criteria_type != "" || criteria_gewicht != "") {

            if (criteria_gewicht != null && criteria_type != null) {

                $('#vermogen_gewicht tr').each(function(i){
                    if ($('.type').html() == criteria_type && $('.gewicht').html() == criteria_gewicht) {
                        $('.type').parent().show();
                    }
                    else{
                        $('.type').parent().hide();
                    }
                });
            }
            else{
                $("p").prepend("Else &&"); //check if I am in else.
            }
        }      
    }
```

This is the html for the buttons:

```
    <div class="filtertype">
        <?php
            foreach ($itemsuniek as $filter) { ?>
            <input type="button" class="filter_button_type button_option" value="<?php echo $filter; ?>" />
        <?php } ?>
    </div>
    <div class="filtertype_gewicht">
        <?php
            foreach ($itemssuniek as $filter) { ?>
            <input type="button" class="filter_button_gewicht button_option" value="<?php echo $filter; ?>" />
        <?php } ?>
    </div>
```

Here is the html on the actual page : Table

```
<table id="vermogen_gewicht" class="table table-hover vermogen_gewicht">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th></th>
            <th>GVW</th>
            <th>Type</th>
            <th>Motor</th>
            <th>kW/pk</th>
            <th>Transmissie</th>
            <th class="prijs">Prijs <span>(excl. BTW/excl. BPM)</span></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>

            <tr class="uitvoering_1         hidden">
        <td class="radiobutton">
        <input type="radio" id="uitvoering_vermogen_gewicht0" value="uitvoering_vermogen_gewicht0" name="uitvoering_vermogen_gewicht" disabled="disabled">

        <label for="uitvoering_vermogen_gewicht0"></label>

        </td>
        <td class="gewicht" id="gewicht">2500</td>
        <td class="type" id="type">L1H1</td>
        <td id="motor">109 CDI</td>
        <td id="kw">65/89</td>
        <td id="transmissie">H6</td>
        <td id="prijs">€16.990</td>
        <td id="prijsinner" class="hidden">16990</td>
    </tr>

            <tr class="uitvoering_2">
        <td class="radiobutton">
        <input type="radio" id="uitvoering_vermogen_gewicht1" value="uitvoering_vermogen_gewicht1" name="uitvoering_vermogen_gewicht">

        <label for="uitvoering_vermogen_gewicht1"></label>

        </td>
        <td class="gewicht" id="gewicht">2500</td>
        <td class="type" id="type">L1H1</td>
        <td id="motor">109 CDI</td>
        <td id="kw">65/89</td>
        <td id="transmissie">H6</td>
        <td id="prijs">€18.985</td>
        <td id="prijsinner" class="hidden">18985</td>
    </tr>
            <tr class="uitvoering_2">
        <td class="radiobutton">
        <input type="radio" id="uitvoering_vermogen_gewicht2" value="uitvoering_vermogen_gewicht2" name="uitvoering_vermogen_gewicht">

        <label for="uitvoering_vermogen_gewicht2"></label>

        </td>
        <td class="gewicht" id="gewicht">2500</td>
        <td class="type" id="type">L2H1</td>
        <td id="motor">109 CDI</td>
        <td id="kw">65/89</td>
        <td id="transmissie">H6</td>
        <td id="prijs">€19.810</td>
        <td id="prijsinner" class="hidden">19810</td>
    </tr>
            <tr class="uitvoering_2">
        <td class="radiobutton">
        <input type="radio" id="uitvoering_vermogen_gewicht3" value="uitvoering_vermogen_gewicht3" name="uitvoering_vermogen_gewicht">

        <label for="uitvoering_vermogen_gewicht3"></label>

        </td>
        <td class="gewicht" id="gewicht">2500</td>
        <td class="type" id="type">L3H1</td>
        <td id="motor">109 CDI</td>
        <td id="kw">65/89</td>
        <td id="transmissie">H6</td>
        <td id="prijs">€20.635</td>
        <td id="prijsinner" class="hidden">20635</td>
    </tr>
            <tr class="uitvoering_2">
        <td class="radiobutton">
        <input type="radio" id="uitvoering_vermogen_gewicht4" value="uitvoering_vermogen_gewicht4" name="uitvoering_vermogen_gewicht">

        <label for="uitvoering_vermogen_gewicht4"></label>

        </td>
        <td class="gewicht" id="gewicht">2500</td>
        <td class="type" id="type">L1H1</td>
        <td id="motor">111 CDI</td>
        <td id="kw">84/114</td>
        <td id="transmissie">H6</td>
        <td id="prijs">€20.900</td>
        <td id="prijsinner" class="hidden">20900</td>
    </tr>
            <tr class="uitvoering_2">
        <td class="radiobutton">
        <input type="radio" id="uitvoering_vermogen_gewicht5" value="uitvoering_vermogen_gewicht5" name="uitvoering_vermogen_gewicht">

        <label for="uitvoering_vermogen_gewicht5"></label>

        </td>
        <td class="gewicht" id="gewicht">2500</td>
        <td class="type" id="type">L2H1</td>
        <td id="motor">111 CDI</td>
        <td id="kw">84/114</td>
        <td id="transmissie">H6</td>
        <td id="prijs">€21.725</td>
        <td id="prijsinner" class="hidden">21725</td>
    </tr>
            <tr class="uitvoering_2">
        <td class="radiobutton">
        <input type="radio" id="uitvoering_vermogen_gewicht6" value="uitvoering_vermogen_gewicht6" name="uitvoering_vermogen_gewicht">

        <label for="uitvoering_vermogen_gewicht6"></label>

        </td>
        <td class="gewicht" id="gewicht">2500</td>
        <td class="type" id="type">L3H1</td>
        <td id="motor">111 CDI</td>
        <td id="kw">84/114</td>
        <td id="transmissie">H6</td>
        <td id="prijs">€22.550</td>
        <td id="prijsinner" class="hidden">22550</td>
    </tr>
            <tr class="uitvoering_2">
        <td class="radiobutton">
        <input type="radio" id="uitvoering_vermogen_gewicht7" value="uitvoering_vermogen_gewicht7" name="uitvoering_vermogen_gewicht">

        <label for="uitvoering_vermogen_gewicht7"></label>

        </td>
        <td class="gewicht" id="gewicht">2500</td>
        <td class="type" id="type">L1H1</td>
        <td id="motor">114 CDI</td>
        <td id="kw">100/136</td>
        <td id="transmissie">H6</td>
        <td id="prijs">€22.415</td>
        <td id="prijsinner" class="hidden">22415</td>
    </tr>
            <tr class="uitvoering_2">
        <td class="radiobutton">
        <input type="radio" id="uitvoering_vermogen_gewicht8" value="uitvoering_vermogen_gewicht8" name="uitvoering_vermogen_gewicht">

        <label for="uitvoering_vermogen_gewicht8"></label>

        </td>
        <td class="gewicht" id="gewicht">2500</td>
        <td class="type" id="type">L2H1</td>
        <td id="motor">114 CDI</td>
        <td id="kw">100/136</td>
        <td id="transmissie">H6</td>
        <td id="prijs">€23.240</td>
        <td id="prijsinner" class="hidden">23240</td>
    </tr>
            <tr class="uitvoering_2">
        <td class="radiobutton">
        <input type="radio" id="uitvoering_vermogen_gewicht9" value="uitvoering_vermogen_gewicht9" name="uitvoering_vermogen_gewicht">

        <label for="uitvoering_vermogen_gewicht9"></label>

        </td>
        <td class="gewicht" id="gewicht">2500</td>
        <td class="type" id="type">L3H1</td>
        <td id="motor">114 CDI</td>
        <td id="kw">100/136</td>
        <td id="transmissie">H6</td>
        <td id="prijs">€24.065</td>
        <td id="prijsinner" class="hidden">24065</td>
    </tr>

            <tr class="uitvoering_3         hidden">
        <td class="radiobutton">
        <input type="radio" id="uitvoering_vermogen_gewicht10" value="uitvoering_vermogen_gewicht10" name="uitvoering_vermogen_gewicht" disabled="disabled">

        <label for="uitvoering_vermogen_gewicht10"></label>

        </td>
        <td class="gewicht" id="gewicht">2800</td>
        <td class="type" id="type">L1H1</td>
        <td id="motor">109 CDI</td>
        <td id="kw">65/89</td>
        <td id="transmissie">H6</td>
        <td id="prijs">€20.900</td>
        <td id="prijsinner" class="hidden">20900</td>
    </tr>
            <tr class="uitvoering_3         hidden">
        <td class="radiobutton">
        <input type="radio" id="uitvoering_vermogen_gewicht11" value="uitvoering_vermogen_gewicht11" name="uitvoering_vermogen_gewicht" disabled="disabled">

        <label for="uitvoering_vermogen_gewicht11"></label>

        </td>
        <td class="gewicht" id="gewicht">2800</td>
        <td class="type" id="type">L2H1</td>
        <td id="motor">109 CDI</td>
        <td id="kw">65/89</td>
        <td id="transmissie">H6</td>
        <td id="prijs">€21.725</td>
        <td id="prijsinner" class="hidden">21725</td>
    </tr>
            <tr class="uitvoering_3         hidden">
        <td class="radiobutton">
        <input type="radio" id="uitvoering_vermogen_gewicht12" value="uitvoering_vermogen_gewicht12" name="uitvoering_vermogen_gewicht" disabled="disabled">

        <label for="uitvoering_vermogen_gewicht12"></label>

        </td>
        <td class="gewicht" id="gewicht">2800</td>
        <td class="type" id="type">L3H1</td>
        <td id="motor">109 CDI</td>
        <td id="kw">65/89</td>
        <td id="transmissie">H6</td>
        <td id="prijs">€22.550</td>
        <td id="prijsinner" class="hidden">22550</td>
    </tr>
            <tr class="uitvoering_3         hidden">
        <td class="radiobutton">
        <input type="radio" id="uitvoering_vermogen_gewicht13" value="uitvoering_vermogen_gewicht13" name="uitvoering_vermogen_gewicht" disabled="disabled">

        <label for="uitvoering_vermogen_gewicht13"></label>

        </td>
        <td class="gewicht" id="gewicht">2800</td>
        <td class="type" id="type">L1H1</td>
        <td id="motor">111 CDI</td>
        <td id="kw">84/114</td>
        <td id="transmissie">H6</td>
        <td id="prijs">€22.815</td>
        <td id="prijsinner" class="hidden">22815</td>
    </tr>
            <tr class="uitvoering_3         hidden">
        <td class="radiobutton">
        <input type="radio" id="uitvoering_vermogen_gewicht14" value="uitvoering_vermogen_gewicht14" name="uitvoering_vermogen_gewicht" disabled="disabled">

        <label for="uitvoering_vermogen_gewicht14"></label>

        </td>
        <td class="gewicht" id="gewicht">2800</td>
        <td class="type" id="type">L2H1</td>
        <td id="motor">111 CDI</td>
        <td id="kw">84/114</td>
        <td id="transmissie">H6</td>
        <td id="prijs">€23.640</td>
        <td id="prijsinner" class="hidden">23640</td>
    </tr>
            <tr class="uitvoering_3         hidden">
        <td class="radiobutton">
        <input type="radio" id="uitvoering_vermogen_gewicht15" value="uitvoering_vermogen_gewicht15" name="uitvoering_vermogen_gewicht" disabled="disabled">

        <label for="uitvoering_vermogen_gewicht15"></label>

        </td>
        <td class="gewicht" id="gewicht">2800</td>
        <td class="type" id="type">L3H1</td>
        <td id="motor">111 CDI</td>
        <td id="kw">84/114</td>
        <td id="transmissie">H6</td>
        <td id="prijs">€24.465</td>
        <td id="prijsinner" class="hidden">24465</td>
    </tr>
            <tr class="uitvoering_3         hidden">
        <td class="radiobutton">
        <input type="radio" id="uitvoering_vermogen_gewicht16" value="uitvoering_vermogen_gewicht16" name="uitvoering_vermogen_gewicht" disabled="disabled">

        <label for="uitvoering_vermogen_gewicht16"></label>

        </td>
        <td class="gewicht" id="gewicht">2800</td>
        <td class="type" id="type">L1H1</td>
        <td id="motor">114 CDI</td>
        <td id="kw">100/136</td>
        <td id="transmissie">H6</td>
        <td id="prijs">€24.330</td>
        <td id="prijsinner" class="hidden">24330</td>
    </tr>
            <tr class="uitvoering_3         hidden">
        <td class="radiobutton">
        <input type="radio" id="uitvoering_vermogen_gewicht17" value="uitvoering_vermogen_gewicht17" name="uitvoering_vermogen_gewicht" disabled="disabled">

        <label for="uitvoering_vermogen_gewicht17"></label>

        </td>
        <td class="gewicht" id="gewicht">2800</td>
        <td class="type" id="type">L2H1</td>
        <td id="motor">114 CDI</td>
        <td id="kw">100/136</td>
        <td id="transmissie">H6</td>
        <td id="prijs">€25.155</td>
        <td id="prijsinner" class="hidden">25155</td>
    </tr>
            <tr class="uitvoering_3         hidden">
        <td class="radiobutton">
        <input type="radio" id="uitvoering_vermogen_gewicht18" value="uitvoering_vermogen_gewicht18" name="uitvoering_vermogen_gewicht" disabled="disabled">

        <label for="uitvoering_vermogen_gewicht18"></label>

        </td>
        <td class="gewicht" id="gewicht">2800</td>
        <td class="type" id="type">L3H1</td>
        <td id="motor">114 CDI</td>
        <td id="kw">100/136</td>
        <td id="transmissie">H6</td>
        <td id="prijs">€25.980</td>
        <td id="prijsinner" class="hidden">25980</td>
    </tr>
            <tr class="uitvoering_3         hidden">
        <td class="radiobutton">
        <input type="radio" id="uitvoering_vermogen_gewicht19" value="uitvoering_vermogen_gewicht19" name="uitvoering_vermogen_gewicht" disabled="disabled">

        <label for="uitvoering_vermogen_gewicht19"></label>

        </td>
        <td class="gewicht" id="gewicht">2800</td>
        <td class="type" id="type">L1H1</td>
        <td id="motor">116 CDI</td>
        <td id="kw">120/163</td>
        <td id="transmissie">H6</td>
        <td id="prijs">€26.060</td>
        <td id="prijsinner" class="hidden">26060</td>
    </tr>
            <tr class="uitvoering_3         hidden">
        <td class="radiobutton">
        <input type="radio" id="uitvoering_vermogen_gewicht20" value="uitvoering_vermogen_gewicht20" name="uitvoering_vermogen_gewicht" disabled="disabled">

        <label for="uitvoering_vermogen_gewicht20"></label>

        </td>
        <td class="gewicht" id="gewicht">2800</td>
        <td class="type" id="type">L2H1</td>
        <td id="motor">116 CDI</td>
        <td id="kw">120/163</td>
        <td id="transmissie">H6</td>
        <td id="prijs">€26.885</td>
        <td id="prijsinner" class="hidden">26885</td>
    </tr>
            <tr class="uitvoering_3         hidden">
        <td class="radiobutton">
        <input type="radio" id="uitvoering_vermogen_gewicht21" value="uitvoering_vermogen_gewicht21" name="uitvoering_vermogen_gewicht" disabled="disabled">

        <label for="uitvoering_vermogen_gewicht21"></label>

        </td>
        <td class="gewicht" id="gewicht">2800</td>
        <td class="type" id="type">L3H1</td>
        <td id="motor">116 CDI</td>
        <td id="kw">120/163</td>
        <td id="transmissie">H6</td>
        <td id="prijs">€27.710</td>
        <td id="prijsinner" class="hidden">27710</td>
    </tr>

            <tr class="uitvoering_4         hidden">
        <td class="radiobutton">
        <input type="radio" id="uitvoering_vermogen_gewicht22" value="uitvoering_vermogen_gewicht22" name="uitvoering_vermogen_gewicht" disabled="disabled">

        <label for="uitvoering_vermogen_gewicht22"></label>

        </td>
        <td class="gewicht" id="gewicht">2800</td>
        <td class="type" id="type">L1H1</td>
        <td id="motor">119 BlueTEC Euro VI</td>
        <td id="kw">140/190</td>
        <td id="transmissie">7G-TRONIC PLUS</td>
        <td id="prijs">€30.395</td>
        <td id="prijsinner" class="hidden">30395</td>
    </tr>
            <tr class="uitvoering_4         hidden">
        <td class="radiobutton">
        <input type="radio" id="uitvoering_vermogen_gewicht23" value="uitvoering_vermogen_gewicht23" name="uitvoering_vermogen_gewicht" disabled="disabled">

        <label for="uitvoering_vermogen_gewicht23"></label>

        </td>
        <td class="gewicht" id="gewicht">2800</td>
        <td class="type" id="type">L2H1</td>
        <td id="motor">119 BlueTEC Euro VI</td>
        <td id="kw">140/190</td>
        <td id="transmissie">7G-TRONIC PLUS</td>
        <td id="prijs">€31.220</td>
        <td id="prijsinner" class="hidden">31220</td>
    </tr>
            <tr class="uitvoering_4         hidden">
        <td class="radiobutton">
        <input type="radio" id="uitvoering_vermogen_gewicht24" value="uitvoering_vermogen_gewicht24" name="uitvoering_vermogen_gewicht" disabled="disabled">

        <label for="uitvoering_vermogen_gewicht24"></label>

        </td>
        <td class="gewicht" id="gewicht">2800</td>
        <td class="type" id="type">L3H1</td>
        <td id="motor">119 BlueTEC Euro VI</td>
        <td id="kw">140/190</td>
        <td id="transmissie">7G-TRONIC PLUS</td>
        <td id="prijs">€32.045</td>
        <td id="prijsinner" class="hidden">32045</td>
    </tr>

        </tbody>
    </table>
```

It has a bit of weird formatting but you can look at the first row and they are all the same.

Here are the buttons :

```
<div class="filtertype">
        <input type="button" value="L1H1" class="filter_button_type button_option">
        <input type="button" value="L2H1" class="filter_button_type button_option">
        <input type="button" value="L3H1" class="filter_button_type button_option">
</div>
```

Comment: why dont you use jquery datatable plugin, it has awsome filtering features. https://www.datatables.net/

Comment: Thank you for answering :) The problem I ran into with Datatable or Tablesorter is that I am only a beginner at jQuery and also don't have the time to search through the api/documentation. Also copy/paste was not an option because none of these plugins have been used with buttons.

Comment: https://www.datatables.net/examples/api/multi_filter_select.html check out this link, it demos filtering based on individual columns.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for answering, I'll check that out asap. I looked at that one already. It will not work for me. I have to check the ROW instead of Column then I have to check for 2 values (my clicked buttons) if they exist in the row do nothing, If they dont exist i hide the row.

Comment: Please post the rendered HTML. PHP has no role in here. This is a basic filtering and can be done using vanilla JavaScript.

Comment: I thought it might be usefull to see how the buttons are created. Also I dont understand what you mean basic filltering with vanilla ? That is a whole framework and i don't have the time/knowledge to do it with that.

Comment: [Vanilla JavaScript](http://vanilla-js.com/). The point of my comment is  there is no need to even use  jQuery or any other library. As an example, Datatables is _overkill_. So please post the markup so we can concentrate on the _implementation_ by analyzing the table and other related DOM elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option for filtering the matching rows is creating an array of filter criteria. This allows you to filter the matching rows flexibly. At first I'd add the index of target cells to the buttons or the parent element of the buttons by using a `data-*` attribute.

```
<div class="filtertype" data-cell-index="2">
        <input type="button" value="L1H1" class="filter_button_type button_option">
        ...
</div>
```

In the above snippet the `data-cell-index` specifies the index of the target cells.

Then we make sure each button group can only have 0 or 1 active button. Then we call the `datadinges` for filtering the rows based on the active buttons:

```
var $button_option = $(".button_option").click(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('active_option').siblings().removeClass('active_option');
    datadinges();
});
```

The `datadinges` gets the active buttons of each group and creates an array of objects. The `index` is the index of the target cells and the `value` is the filtering value:

```
// cache the rows for better performance
var $rows = $('#vermogen_gewicht tbody tr');

function datadinges() {
   // create an array of objects based on the active buttons
   var filterCriteria = $button_option.filter('.active_option').map(function() {
      return {
         index: +this.parentNode.getAttribute('data-cell-index'),
         value: this.value
      }
   }).get();

   // get the length of the array
   var len = filterCriteria.length;

   // if there is no criteria show all the rows
   if ( len === 0 ) {
     return $rows.removeClass('hidden');
   }

   // hide all the rows and then show the matching rows
   $rows.addClass('hidden').filter(function(i, row) {
      // if the length of filtered criteria list 
      // is equal to the length of all filters
      return filterCriteria.filter(function(filter) {
          return row.cells[filter.index].textContent === filter.value;
      }).length === len;

   }).removeClass('hidden');
}
```

[Here is a demo on jsfiddle.net.](http://jsfiddle.net/eb8L19mz/)

Now you can add more button groups to your markup and use the `data-filter-index` attribute for specifying the index of the target cells. We could also use the text of the header cells as filtering keys instead of the indices but that needs another iteration.

Comment: Thanks so much for the reply, The data-cell-index is what exactly ?

Comment: @GertjanBrouwer You are very welcome. It's just an attribute. `data-*` attribute is part of HTML5 standard. They allow you store custom data in attributes.

Comment: Oh my, My man you are the best. This worked. Thanks so so so much. I will be checking out how it works now because I don't understand it :)

Comment: @GertjanBrouwer You are very welcome, indeed. I have added some comments to the code snippets. I hope it's more understandable now.